# After using logging module, my python script hangs

Tags: python, shell, subprocess

I tried to make a log file in a python script. After adding the line below

```
logging.basicConfig(filename='LOG_FILE.log',
                    filemode='w',
                    format='%(asctime)s %(message)s',
                    level=logging.DEBUG)
```

the script simply hangs when I try to execute any shell script using `os.system` or `commands.getoutput`.

It works when I do not use this line.

Comment: #!/usr/local/bin/python2.7
import commands
import logging
logging.basicConfig(filename='Log_file.log',filemode='w',format='%(asctime)s %(message)s',level=logging.DEBUG)
changes = commands.getoutput('SCRIPT.sh <arg1> <arg2> | wc -l')
print changes

-- HANGS --

#!/usr/local/bin/python2.7
import commands
changes = commands.getoutput('SCRIPT.sh <arg1> <arg2> | wc -l')
print changes

--PRINTS OUTPUT--

Comment: Works fine for me, but the code you show here is not the code you actually run, isn't it? What is in SCRIPT.sh and what are the actual commands you used to invoke it?

Comment: Its actually a binary file that am trying to run here. . I will be specifying branch and couple of numbers as arguments. And this command is supposed to return me back the number of items available between those numbers in that particular branch. For eg : range <branch> <Begin_Number> <End_Number>

Comment: When I use trace. python -m file --trace SCRIPT.py. Hangs here
commands.py(58):     import os
commands.py(59):     pipe = os.popen('{ ' + cmd + '; } 2>&1', 'r')
commands.py(60):     text = pipe.read()

Comment: Strange. It looks like the command never finishes to write. But why that only happens when logging is imported I do not know. What happens if you rework `commands.getoutput` to `subprocess.check_output`?

Comment: Used subprocess.check_output and it hangs too . . here is the trace.
subprocess.py(727):             if self.stdin:
subprocess.py(731):             elif self.stdout:
subprocess.py(732):                 stdout = self.stdout.read()

Comment: don't put the relevant info in the comments. [edit] your question instead. Try to [create a minimal, complete code example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)